# Sqlalchemy create a database table manually

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to create a table without using `Base.metadata.create_all()`. I'm looking for something like `Mytable.create()` which should create only its corresponding table.

The reason I want to do so is because i'm using Postgres schemas for a multi-tenant web app and I want to create the `public` tables(`User`etc) separately and the user specific(each having a separate schema, ex. `Blog`,`Post`) tables when the user signs up. However all the definitions lie in the same file and it seems that create_all creates all the tables defined in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read documentation [Creating and Dropping Database Tables](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables).

You can do `user_table.create(engine)`, or if you are using declarative extension: `User.__table__.create(engine)`.

Comment: And you were right, only we are able to access those `tables` for each model.